# Concatenating hexbin objects (or other methods to iteratively construct hexbin plots with extremely large datasets)

Tags: r, plot

I have a dataset with 12,000 participants. Each participant is associated with two 360x360 matrices (one matrix representing distance between two brain regions, and another showing a correlation representing the connectedness of the two brain regions over time). I want to plot distance x correlation for all regions, combining all participants, in one plot. That's 1,555,200,000 data points, and R won't assign a vector for even one axis of that size. Ideally I'd also like to plot a best fit line over it.

The strategy I'm attempting is to calculate the number of points in a series of hex bins for each participant using the hexbin package, and then sum them iteratively so that I have counts for each bin across all participants. However, I cannot figure out how to do the sum operation, as there is no concatenate method in the hexbin package (or equivalent functionality anywhere else I've looked).

So basically I want to do something like this:

```
library(mc2d)
library(hexbin)
N=10000
x1<-rpert(N,0,2,4,shape=5)
y1<-rpert(N,2,8,10,shape=5)
x2<-rpert(N,6,8,10,shape=5)
y2<-rpert(N,0,2,8,shape=5)
xc<-c(x1,x2)
yc<-c(y1,y2)

h1<-hexbin(x1,y1,xbnds=c(0,10),ybnds=c(0,10),xbins=100,shape=.75)
h2<-hexbin(x2,y2,xbnds=c(0,10),ybnds=c(0,10),xbins=100,shape=.75)
hc<-hexbin(xc,yc,xbnds=c(0,10),ybnds=c(0,10),xbins=100,shape=.75)

plot(hc)
```

[image: Combined hex plot]

Except that I want to generate hc from h1 and h2, instead of from the component vectors (because those would be too large to hold in memory for my actual application). I'm open to using python or another language if it would get the job done.

Answer (score 2):

I think this works:

### unpack hexbin object

extract either values (as columns of a data frame) or metadata

```r
unpack_hexbin <- function(x, element = c("cols", "metadata")) {
    element <- match.arg(element)
    get_slots <- function(nm) Map(\(c) getElement(x, c), nm)
    cols <- c("cell", "count", "xcm", "ycm")
    if (element == "cols") return(get_slots(cols) |>
                                  do.call(what = "data.frame"))
    other_slots <- setdiff(slotNames(x), c(cols, "call", "n", "ncells"))
    get_slots(other_slots)
}
```

### combine

Take a list of hexbin objects.

- Extract and merge the data columns
- Sum the values associated with each cell, skipping `NA`s
- Extract the metadata from the **first** hexbin object (assuming they are all consistent!)
- Put the pieces back together

```r
combine_hexbin <- function(L) {
    h <- Map(unpack_hexbin, L)
    h2 <- Reduce(\(x,y) 
        merge(x, y, by = c("cell", "xcm", "ycm"), all = TRUE),
           h)
    comb <- apply(h2[,-(1:3)], 1, sum, na.rm = TRUE)
    do.call(new,
            c(list("hexbin"),
              as.list(h2[,1:3]),
              list(count = comb,
                   n = sum(comb),
                   ncells = length(comb)),
              unpack_hexbin(L[[1]], "metadata"),
              call = quote(call("junk", 1))
            ))
}
```

### try it out

With values from example above:

```r
L <- list(h1, h2)
cc <- combine_hexbin(L)
plot(cc)
```

Comment: Nice! I think it would be worth also updating the value of the `n` and `ncells` slots in the final hexbin. And it seems you have one extra definition of `get_slots()` in `unpack_hexbin()`.

Comment: oops, yes.  Feel free to edit if I don't get around to it ...

Comment: Ok, I modified your code slightly so that it updates the `n` and `ncells` slots.

Comment: Amazing -- thanks so much! This solves the example nicely. A complication is that the xcm and ycm parameters are the center of mass within each hex, not the coordinates. So if the hexplots have any overlap, the merge above creates a duplicate record for the same cell with a different center of mass, resulting in overplotting. I think what I need to do is re-calculate the center of mass based on the weights. I think I can do this using either hcell2xy or hcell2xyInt from hexbin to look up the coordinates. I'll post back if I sort it. This solution gives me courage!

Answer (score 0):

Ben's answer is very close, but xcm and ycm in the hexbin object are the center of mass and are not unique to the cell, so merging on them produces duplicates incorrectly if the data overlaps at all. A key piece of information is that the cell IDs are unique to a specific hex in the grid defined by the bounding information (you can find this out by comparing overlapping ranges of cell ids in hexbins that do and do not overlap -- or by looking at x and y coordinates output by the hcell2xy function). So, as long as the bounds of the two hexbins are identical, you can simply merge on cellID.

Problem restatement with overlapping data:

```
N=10000
x1<-rpert(N,0,2,4,shape=5)
y1<-rpert(N,2,8,10,shape=5)
x2<-rpert(N,0,5,10,shape=5)
y2<-rpert(N,0,5,10,shape=5)


h1<-hexbin(x1,y1,xbnds=c(0,10),ybnds=c(0,10),xbins=100,shape=.75)
h2<-hexbin(x2,y2,xbnds=c(0,10),ybnds=c(0,10),xbins=100,shape=.75)
```

[image: Plot of H1]

[image: Plot of H2]

Solution (adapted from Ben's):

```
# Get elements from s4 object by name
get_slots <- function(x,nm) Map(\(c) getElement(x, c), nm)

# Unpack hexbin data to be merged in to a dataframe
# Strictly speaking we don't need the xy coordinates, but it is a good error
# check if we have the computation time available.
unpack_hexbin <- function(x) {
  cols <- c("cell", "count", "xcm", "ycm")
  return(cbind(data.frame(get_slots(x,cols)),
                 hcell2xy(x)))
}

# Get columns from a dataframe that should not vary between hexbins to be 
# merged.
getmeta_hexbin <- function(x) {
  varying=c("cell", "count", "xcm", "ycm", "call", "n", "ncells")
  other_slots <- setdiff(slotNames(x), varying)
  get_slots(x,other_slots)
}

# Center of mass calculation for two points, robust to missing data. 
cm<-function(x1,x2,x1w,x2w) {
  i<-x1*x1w
  j<-x2*x2w
  w<-sum(x1w,x2w,na.rm=TRUE)
  return(sum(i,j,na.rm=TRUE)/w)
}

combine_hexbin <- function(a,b) {
    hm <- merge(unpack_hexbin(a), 
                unpack_hexbin(b), 
                by = c("cell","x","y"), 
                all = TRUE)
    if(any(duplicated(hm$cell))) stop("Duplicate cell Id's detected: Do the hexbin objects have the same grid?")
    hm2 <- hm %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(
      count=sum(count.x,count.y,na.rm=TRUE),
      xcm=cm(xcm.x,xcm.y,count.x,count.y),
      ycm=cm(ycm.x,ycm.y,count.x,count.y)
    )
    do.call(new,
            c(list("hexbin"),
              as.list(hm2[,c("cell",
                             "count",
                             "xcm",
                             "ycm")]),
              list(n = sum(hm2$count),
                   ncells = length(hm2)),
              getmeta_hexbin(a),
              call = quote(call("merged hexbin", 1))
            ))
}

plot(combine_hexbin(h1,h2))
```

[image: Combined plot of overlapping data]